# What next to do after mikrotik sends an ret during user creation

Tags: mikrotik, router-os

I am trying to communicate with a Mikrotik RouterOS to create a new user as follows

```
 $usermanagerQuery = new Query(
            "/tool/user-manager/user/add",
            [
                '=customer=admin',
                '=username=sampleuser',
                '=password=samplepassword',
                '=shared-users=1',
                '=caller-id-bind-on-first-use=yes'
            ]
        );

        $userCreationResponse = $client->query($usermanagerQuery)->read(false);
```

Now I got a response of

```
Array ( [0] => !done [1] => =ret=*A85 )
```

What next do I need to do with the response above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more. Your request is accomplished.

As [api doc](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API), `!done` is the first word of router reply that last sentence send by client is `OK`.
If there was any problem the response would be `!trap`

In the response array, the router is telling you OK ( !done) , and giving you the id of the last data entry `*A85`, if you need to manipulate on current session.